# how to store value in database every 24 hour php cronjob

Tags: php, mysqli, cron

am running script with cronjob to run script every 24 hours, but  am getting problem when i refresh the page also its updating, i want run specified time run script .

am using below code

```
$dif = time();

if ($dif < time()+1) {

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bitmining");
$test = "Hello";
$las_d = date("y-m-d");
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO php_cron(last_ts, value) VALUES('$las_d','$test')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
    echo "Updated!";
}
```

am new to php can anyone help me to solve this problem

Comment: Also, store the time, check if last entry time less than 24 hours, don't update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve this storing date in DB everytime you execute CRON.

Check it before do insert.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bitmining");
$dif = time();
$date = "SELECT date_insert FROM php_cron ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1";
//84300 are 24h in seconds.
if ($date+84300 > time()){
    if ($conn){
        $sql3 = "INSERT INTO php_cron(last_ts, value, date_insert) VALUES('$las_d','$test','".time()."')";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql3))
        {
            echo "Updated!";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "There is an error.";
        }
    }
}
else {
echo "Not yet!";
}
?>
```

Comment: You are not running the $date  query

Comment: Hi thank you this function work after 24hours only . Am getting output like "not yet"

Comment: Maybe my code can't run literally, but I think logic is okay, if you need it literally just ask for it ;)

Comment: I sloved it thank you . I just run $date query .now its working. Am just getting confused. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work just copying.
Let's try!

```
 <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "stacks");
$dif = time();
$sql = "SELECT date_insert FROM php_cron ORDER BY date_insert DESC LIMIT 1";
$old_date = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ($old_date->num_rows > 0) {
    $older_date = $old_date->fetch_assoc()['date_insert'];
    $now_date = date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $old_timestamp = date_create(date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( $older_date ) ));
    $diff=date_diff($old_timestamp,$now_date);

    if ($diff->days >= 1){
        if ($conn){
            $las_d = "Input here your values";
            $test = "Input here your values";
            $now_date_updated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $sql3 = "INSERT INTO php_cron(last_ts, value, date_insert) VALUES('".$las_d."','".$test."','".$now_date_updated."')";

            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql3))
            {
                echo "Updated!";
            }
            else
            {
              echo "There is an error.";
            }
        }
    }
    else {
    echo "Not yet!";
    }
}

?>
```